# How I hide react code from browser console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Does anyone know how to hide the code displayed in the browser console?

I use in package.json `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` and  `set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts` build and run npm run build and delete the .js.map files but it doesn't work...

Comment: You can't hide code from the browser. If the browser can't see the code, then the browser can't run the code, then your web page won't work properly - if you have super sensitive information in your code, then re-think your code - what does the image have to do with the question anyway

Comment: Please may you be clearer? Do you want to hide all code? Or just some of the files? You mention source maps, do you want to hide those?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I want to hide the code that is in the util folder

Comment: No you cannot hide that folder.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, so what could I do so that the code is not seen...?

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Look, what happens is that I have this vulnerability "161. Missing secure obfuscation" What was recommended for this was to obfuscate the code, however, I have React and Typescript code (Which according to me is not possible to obfuscate or not I know very well) And they report that vulnerability as a JavaScript code, so I don't know what I can do for that, I try to hide the code but it doesn't work for me and I don't know what to do anymore. I hope to be clear :( ...

Answer (score 4):

in package.json file as follows.
add GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false to build

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

if you use create-react-app, create a .env file in the root of the project and paste in `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

Comment: Although helpful, this doesn’t answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called .env in the src folder then add this code GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

Comment: I try and it doesn't work...